# Conversion of VS 2010 project to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, migration

I downloaded some sample ASP .NET projects from net. But they are in VS2010 format. I use VS 2008. How can I change the format?

Comment: unwise, I would say, at best.

Comment: are the sample projects dotnet 4? if so then they cannot be run outside of vs2010

Comment: Can u tell me a place to find good source codes of VS2008 for beginners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *try* to create a brand new solution and create new projects from the existing source (File | New | Project From Existing Code).  However, if they're using any .Net 4.0 features (or certain C# 4.0 features like dynamic) then you'll be out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a 2008 project and migrate it to 2010, only the .csproj, .vbproj, .sln files etc will actually change. So in theory you could try to edit these back to 2008 values. However, the actual code in the samples may be aimed at a different version of the .NET Framework than you have.

I would recommend creating a new ASP.NET project in VS 2008, then using Add, Add Existing Item to add the pages, config files etc from the samples into your project. Then edit them to fix any issues with using functionaliy you don't have.

Or better still, go find some samples for the version of VS and the version of the .NET Framework that you are actually using.